# Simple MVC in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pretty new in VBA but I can learn quickly so I just need some reference to point me to the right direction.

I'm implementing a monthly report in Excel, each row representing a task assigned on a certain day, according a predefined sequence of tasks for that month.

I'd like to use a column "IsAccomplished" so that when I enter the value "No", the sequence of the remaining tasks shifts below to the next available, maintaining its order, as in this example:

```
Day ¦   IsAccomplished  ¦ Task
----+-------------------+-------
1   ¦       Yes         ¦ task1
2   ¦       Yes         ¦ task2
3   ¦       Yes         ¦ task3
4   ¦       Yes         ¦ task4
```

...

becomes

```
Day ¦   IsAccomplished  ¦ Task
----+-------------------+-------
1   ¦       Yes         ¦ task1
2   ¦       No          ¦ 
3   ¦       Yes         ¦ task2
4   ¦       Yes         ¦ task3
```

...

It looks like an MVC problem and I don't know if it can be done in Excel, so any guidance is really appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Looks like something pretty straightforward you can use COUNTIF() for...

Answer (score 1):

No VBA needed, if I understand correctly.

Assuming it's columns A, B, and C, in C2, you can put:

```
=IF(OR($B2="",$B2="No"),"","task"&COUNTIF($B$2:$B2,"Yes"))
```

and drag down.